# How to get a transparent and even effect printed on card board?

Tags: print-design, print-production, color-reproduction, overprint

I want the card to shine through an even pink colour. Do I use silk screen? Overprint? Transparency? How to get this even and without the dots from the screen showing?[image]

Comment: At first glance you will have a toooooon of problems printing on that material. That will suck the ink like a hungry monster. 
Overprint has nothing to do with this because we have no idea what are you printing.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with offset or silk screen or even most other printing methods. You'll need to print the pink as a solid color (eg. Pantone Uncoated, no screen, no cmyk). Usually the printing colors are not opaque, so the cardboard will be 'tinted' not laquered. It's not complicated, but always talk to your printer (the man, not the device) to make sure he knows what you want to do. The grey value of the cardboard will add up to the pink, so choose a slightly brighter pink or it will get darker than you expect.

Comment: Thank you. Just so I understand you correctly. I need to use pantone, but not silk screen method. The correct is offset? However I am not sure the printer (the device) for offset handle the card as it is too thick (3 mm) and hence they use the silk screen press. When you say "tinted" do you mean the raster/dots will show? I am trying to talk to the printer (man), but there is a language barrier as the publisher I work use a printhouse in another country.

Comment: For 3mm cardboard silk screen printing might be necessary (The cardboard can't be bended, so you need a process that's able to print on flat material). Raster/dots won't be there if you print a solid color in 100%. Assign a Pantone Uncoated (Spot) color and make sure it's not translated into CMYK (Halftones). It might be a good idea to create a little mockup image of your design similar the one you attached above, to show your printer (the man) what the result should look like.

Comment: I am really grateful for your advise and I have made a mockup and sent off. The printers (sales) have now promised to get me in touch with the printers (man). I cross my fingers and hope for the perfect result and I am so happy to learn something new every day!

Comment: @munchdesigner Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.